# InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes with Keras LSTM Net

Tags: python, keras, lstm, reshape, shapes

I want to predict the pressure of a machine. I have 18 input values and the pressure as output. So I have 19 columns and 7657 rows as the database consists of 7657 time steps and each counts for 1 sec.

I have a problem with the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn import linear_model  
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense #Standard neural network layer
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Activation 
from keras.layers import Dropout

df = pd.read_csv('Testdaten_2_Test.csv',delimiter=';')

feature_col_names=['LSDI','LZT1I', ..... ,'LZT5I']
predicted_class_names = ['LMDI']

x = df[feature_col_names].values
y = df[predicted_class_names].values

x_train_size = 6400
x_train, x_test = x[0:x_train_size], x[x_train_size:len(x)]

y_train_size = 6400
y_train, y_test = y[0:y_train_size], y[y_train_size:len(y)]

nb_model = linear_model.LinearRegression()
nb_model.fit(X=x_train, y=y_train)

nb_predict_train = nb_model.predict(x_test)

from sklearn import metrics

def scale(x, y):
    # fit scaler
    x_scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
    x_scaler = x_scaler.fit(x)
    x_scaled = x_scaler.transform(x)

    # fit scaler
    y_scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
    y_scaler = y_scaler.fit(y)
    y_scaled = y_scaler.transform(y)
    return x_scaler, y_scaler, x_scaled, y_scaled

x_scaler, y_scaler, x_scaled, y_scaled = scale(x, y)
x_train, x_test = x_scaled[0:x_train_size], x_scaled[x_train_size:len(x)]
y_train, y_test = y_scaled[0:y_train_size], y_scaled[y_train_size:len(y)]

x_train=x_train.reshape(x_train_size,1,18)
y_train=y_train.reshape(y_train_size,1,1)

model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(10, return_sequences=True,batch_input_shape=(32,1,18)))  
model.add(LSTM(10,return_sequences=True))  
model.add(LSTM(1,return_sequences=True, activation='linear'))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=        
['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10,batch_size=32)

score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test,batch_size=32)

predicted = model.predict(x_test)
predicted = y_scaler.inverse_transform(predicted)
predicted = [x if x > 0 else 0 for x in predicted]

correct_values = y_scaler.inverse_transform(y_test)
correct_values = [x if x > 0 else 0 for x in correct_values]
print(nb_predict_train)
```

I Get the Error:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have 3
>   dimensions, but got array with shape (1257, 18)

After the last line of code.

I also tried to reshape the test data but then I get a very similar error.

I think, I'm missing something very easy or basic but I can't figure it out at the moment, as I'm just a beginner in coding neuronal networks.
I need this for my master thesis so I would be very thank full if anyone could help me out.

Comment: You forget reshape `x_test` like `x_train`.

Comment: Hi I already did that. When add:

    x_test=x_test.reshape(1257,1,18)
    y_test=y_test.reshape(1257,1,1)

In the End i get the Error:

InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [9,10] vs. [32,10]
 [[Node: lstm_1/while/add_5 = Add[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](lstm_1/while/BiasAdd_2, lstm_1/while/MatMul_6)]]

Comment: to those getting similar error can check this link as well https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11749 - changing the metrics used could help in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your model input `batch_input_shape` is fixed. The length of your test length is 1257 and cannot be divisible by 32. It should be changed as follows:

```
model.add(LSTM(10, return_sequences=True,batch_input_shape=(None,1,18)))
```

You should modify test shape before the model evaluate test.

```
x_test= x_test.reshape(len(x)-x_train_size,1,18)
y_test= y_test.reshape(len(y)-x_train_size,1,1)
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test,batch_size=32)
```

Of course, you have to reshape `predicted` and `y_test` before `inverse_transform`.

```
predicted = model.predict(x_test)
predicted= predicted.reshape(len(y)-x_train_size,1)
y_test= y_test.reshape(len(y)-x_train_size,1)
```

Comment: Hi,

thank you very much, now my code works.

Could you tell me why the batch size is fixed at 32? I know that I put the Input in the model at 32 but I think I needed to do this so that my code gave me any output besides of Error.

In generell I Don't understand the principle of batching and shaping or reshaping.

Do you got some suggestions where i could get some more knowledge about this specific topics?

And again thank you very much. Is it better if i would write this text as an answer instead of an comment? (I'm new to this page :D)

Comment: @D.Luipers Welcome here. You‘d better write text as comment if your text can't answer quertions directly. It is generally believed that batch size is not important in DL. So you can set the value at will. Whether to use shaping or reshaping depends on your model input and usage. In short, you need to practice more. Finally, don't forget to accept the answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but i think i got problems to understand the input shape and data shape when you use a LSTM Model. I understand it that my input data shape should be = (number of rows, value in each row, number of columns). I read that you also can include the number of look_backs but i get an error if i want to fit this in. Do you got any suggestions? Thank you very much

Comment: @D.Luipers You need read some 
keras documentions(https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#lstm) and examples(http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lstm.html or https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/ and so on).